# Append strings in UILabel?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, nsstring, uilabel

I have 10 UIButtons and Single UILabel.All these UIButtons have Some Text as a title.Now i want  when i click Some UIButton its title assign to UILabel and when we Click on Second UIButton its title also assign to UIlabel and append its with text of UILabel that it already have. Here is my code.

```
  - (void)aMethod:(id)sender {

    UIButton *button = (UIButton *)sender;
    NSString    *get = (NSString *)[[button titleLabel] text];
    NSLog(@"my uibutton test= %@",get);
    mainlabel.text=get;

 }
```

Please any one guide me how can i Appened all these UIButtons Titles in Single UILabel.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to create a new string by appending them:

```
// ..
NSString origText = mainlabel.text;
mainlabel.text = [origText stringByAppendingString:get];
```

Comment: also if you need space between... mainlabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@ %@", mainlabel.text, get];

Comment: Thanx @Binyamin Sharet Dear Using your Code i done this..Thanx for helping

Answer (score 2):

You need to make the string modifiable. Try something like:

```
NSMutableString * newLabel = [NSMutableString stringWithString:mainlabel.text];

[newLabel appendString:@" "];
[newlabel appendString:get];

mainLabel.text = newLabel;
```

or something along those lines.

Comment: Thanx @Dirk-Willem van Gulik for helping me.

Answer (score 1):

NVM:  Binyamin Sharet's code is perfect

How about this?

```
- (void)aMethod:(id)sender {

UIButton *button = (UIButton *)sender;
NSString    *get = [sender currentTitle];
NSLog(@"my uibutton test= %@",get);
mainlabel.text=get;

 }
```

But a much simple way is 
typecast id to UIButton so

```
- (void)aMethod:(UIButton *)sender {
mainLabel.text = [sender currentTitle];
}
```

Comment: hmm i was just reading code now i read his actual problem and your solution is perfect

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
 mainLabel.text = [mainLabel.text stringByAppendingFormat:@" %@",get];
```